# Distribution of random generator

Tags: random, entropy

I have a prng, which generates 32-bit numbers. It has a uniform distribution.
I want it to generate 8-bit numbers. 
When I split my 32-bit number into 4 8 bit and measure entropy of sequence, then it has something near 8 bits of entropy per byte. Sequence length is 1 mb.
When I generate 8-bit numbers like this: `generate_number() mod 255`, and measure entropy of sequence it's like 1.7 bits per byte. 
I'm measuring entropy using [ent](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/)
How can I get random numbers of lower bitness if I have random number generator of higher bitness?

Comment: I don't understand your first two sentences. Does "32-bit numbers" mean integers from $0$ to $2^{32}-1$? If so, then what does "standard normal distribution" mean? What is the mean and what is the standard deviation? Isn't the PRNG producing uniformly distributed random numbers?

Comment: @Somos, yes, my bad, it has a uniform ditribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some languages use mod $256$ instead of mod $255$.
In C for example the bitwise AND-operator have a maximum value of $255$ for one byte.
But if you use the %-operator it takes a maximum value of $256$. Both these operators behave differently. This is not a mathematical problem, but a coders-mistake. In any case a solution might be:

```
generate_number() mod 256
```

or

```
generate_number() & 255
```

It depends on the programming language what these moduluses do.
Having a wrong number for the modulo operation would drastically change the entropy value.

If this doesnt resolve the problem. One step is to shift-right the $32$-bit value by $8$, $16$, $24$ and so on, and check the higher order bits instead of the lower ones, if there is something strange with the lower-order bits.

Using shift-right to check other byte-regions in C: `(generate_number() >> 8) mod 256` and exchange `8` with `16` or `24` et cetera for other byte regions.

We don't know enough detailed information about the Random generator you use to say whats exactly causing the entropy change. But I expect my answer is of use based on the information given.